# Python setuptools_scm get version from git tags

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, setuptools-scm

I am using project.toml file to package my module, I want to extract the version from git tag using `setuptools_scm` module.

When I run `python setup.p y --version` command it gives this output `0.0.1.post1.dev0`. How will I get only `0.0.1` value and omit the `.post.dev0` value?

Here is project.toml file settings:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=46.1.0", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=5"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
version_scheme = "no-guess-dev"
local_scheme="no-local-version"
write_to = "src/showme/version.py"
git_describe_command = "git describe --dirty --tags --long --match v* --first-parent"

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "showme.__version__"}
```

output:

```
 python setup.py --version
setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py:108: _BetaConfiguration: Support for `[tool.setuptools]` in `pyproject.toml` is still *beta*.
  warnings.warn(msg, _BetaConfiguration)
0.0.1.post1.dev0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setuptools_scm` out-of-the-box generates development and post-release versions.

To generate a release version like `0.0.1`, you can pass a callable into `use_scm_version`:

```py
# content of setup.py

def myversion():
    from setuptools_scm.version import SEMVER_MINOR, guess_next_simple_semver, release_branch_semver_version

    def my_release_branch_semver_version(version):
        v = release_branch_semver_version(version)
        if v == version.format_next_version(guess_next_simple_semver, retain=SEMVER_MINOR):
            return version.format_next_version(guess_next_simple_semver, fmt="{guessed}", retain=SEMVER_MINOR)
        return v

    return {
        'version_scheme': my_release_branch_semver_version,
        'local_scheme': 'no-local-version',
    }


setup(use_scm_version=myversion)
```

Reference: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm#importing-in-setuppy